# How to resolve this error : Local declaration of 'indexPath' hides instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have create a project. In this using a tableview methods. I have run this project so run is successfully. And working good But I have some problem create. I have many times to try but not resolved. so please suggest me how to resolve this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

LocationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htrcell"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
[cell.location_lbl setTitle:location[indexPath.row]forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.bg_view.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
cell.bg_view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.bg_view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:20.0/255 green:100.0/255 blue:171.0/255 alpha:0.7f] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f];

////////////////
[cell.map addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedMap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.map setTag:indexPath.row];    

[cell.phone addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedPhone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.phone setTag:indexPath.row];

[cell.location_lbl addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedlocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.location_lbl setTag:indexPath .row];


return cell;
}
```

In this `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method All `indexPath` place to show the issues. Like this line in this

```
[cell.location_lbl setTitle:location[indexPath.row]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`indexPath` place to show issues:

> Local declaration of `indexPath` hides instance variable.

How to resolve my problem.
Thankyou

Comment: You have a global variable with same name "indexPath" in the header or something. Change that one to "myIndexPath" or something else.

Comment: I replace "indexPath" to "myindexPath"?

Comment: yes, you replace, but not in method "cellForRowAtIndexPath", in definitions of your globals.

Comment: How please suggest in some codes.

Comment: Did you wrote somewhere something like this? NSIndexPath *indexPath;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you have declared variable, named "indexPath" in your class interface. Change this name.

Comment: I cant understand please explain in briefly

Comment: check your places in this class (.m & .h files) where did you did declared any variables, and probably one of them named "indexPath", which is exactly like the name of variable-parameter at the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath". Rename variable 'indexPath", that you've created, to any other name.

Comment: its a stupid mistake, I change variable name and solve my problem. Thank yo so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If any time, its showing Local declaration of 'yourVairableName' hides instance variable then it means you created your local variable name same as your instance variable.

So please check and confirm that you did't create any local variable with the same name as indexPath.